# Forever running programm computable?

Tags: computability

Is a forever running program computable? For example a program which calculates the biggest natural number.

Comment: Have you seen definition of computable program? What does it say?

Comment: Computability is a property of *languages* or *functions*, not of programs.

Comment: You want another model of computation than the classic one used in lectures on computability.

Comment: Note that your question is self-answering: you are asking whether the function computed by a diverging program is actually computed by some program.